# JQuery chosen plugin - Sending the user typed input to an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I am trying to populate the drop down using Chosen plugin for multiple select.

I have added the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/san1234/ymnj12xk/

My intention is to populate the "options" tag in the "select" tag, basing on JSON data obtained by sending user typed letter via the Ajax call.

For this I need to know, how to make an ajax call onkeyup i.e. if the user typed "Am", i want to send that input to an Ajax call and get the JSON response, something like ["America","Amsterdam"]

I'm new to this and I cant figure out a way to extract the user typed input in the 'select' box to actually send it as request in an Ajax call.

I have tried doing this but 'autocomplete' method in the JS file doesn't work
How do i do this? kindly help!

**JS file**

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

$(".chosen-select-deselect").chosen({
  allow_single_deselect: true
});
$('.chosen-choices input').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({

      url: "/someURL/" + request.term + "/",
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('ul.chosen-results').empty();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Success!");
        response($.map(data, function(item) {

          $('ul.chosen-results').append('<li class="active-result">' + item.name + '</li>');
        }));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select class="chosen chosen-select" multiple="" data-placeholder="Choose a Country" style="width:200px">
    <option value="America">America</option>
     <option value="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
      <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
    <option value="GHI">hij</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Java is not related to JavaScript

Comment: Seems like you have more than one question here. Some of them (how do I extract text from a text input) pretty much just have one answer. Others (how do I send data to my server) have many possible valid answers, and will depend on the tools that you're using. I think you should do some more research on which tools you're using, which tools you want to use, and maybe post that here. There's no technical context for the whole server side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you are using PHP in your back end or any other program language but here's my solution using php and javascript :

First your javaScript:

```
//initialization of chosen select
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  search_contains: true // an option to search between words
});
$(".chosen-select-deselect").chosen({
  allow_single_deselect: true
});

//ajax function to search a new value to the dropdown list
function _ajaxSearch (param){
  return $.ajax({
    url: "request.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {param:param}
  })
}
//key event to call our ajax call
$(".chosen-choices input").on('keyup',function(){
  var  param = $('.chosen-choices input').val();// get the pressed key
  _ajaxSearch(param)
  .done(function(response){
    var exists; // variable that returns a true if the value already exists in our dropdown list
    $.each(response,function(index, el) { //loop to check if the value exists inside the list
      $('#mySelect option').each(function(){
        if (this.value == el.key) {
          exists = true;
        }
      });
      if (!exists) {// if the value does not exists, added it to the list
        $("#mySelect").append("<option value="+el.key+">"+el.value+"</option>");
        var ChosenInputValue = $('.chosen-choices input').val();//get the current value of the search
        $("#mySelect").trigger("chosen:updated");//update the list
        $('.chosen-choices input').val(ChosenInputValue);//since the update method reset the input fill the input with the value already typed
      }
    });
  })
})
```

your php file:

```
if (isset($_POST["param"])) {// check is the param is set
$param = $_POST["param"]; // get the value of the param
$array  = array('JKL' => 'jkl' , 'MNO'=>'mno', 'PQR'=>'pqr','STU'=>'stu','VWX'=>'vwx','YZ'=>'yz' );//array of values
$matches = array();//array of matches
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){//loop to check the values
        //check for match.
        if(strpos($value, $param) !== false){
            //add to matches array.
            $matches[]= array ("key"=> $key,"value"=>$value);
        }
    }
//send the response using json format
echo json_encode($matches);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me.I'm using struts in my AngularJS application to fetch JSON data and I'm able to load data to my dropdown.The 'exists' logic that you've mentioned here is not required in my case and I have modified the append statement this way $("#mySelect").append("<li class=\"active-result\" value="+el+">"+el+"</li>");

Comment: But I'm facing an error when i try to select an option from the dropdown. I see the error 'Unable to set property 'selected' of undefined or null reference' in the Chosen.prototype.result_select() at the line, item=this.results_data[high[0].getAttribute("data-option-array-item")] as  high[0].getAttribute("data-option-array-item") is giving null. And as a result, i could see <li class="result-selected"> after selecting an item but, it is not getting added to my input box. Could you help me out with this. Sorry I'm not allowed to share my code hence I've shared my analysis. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have noticed that this attribute data-option-array-item is not present in my <li> tag. My <li> tag looks something like this <li class="active-result" value="ghi">ghi</li> now. Could you help me out in resolving this issue.!

Comment: @San I dont really know how angluar works ? In order to help u somehow can u share the error in your question with some screen captures ?

Comment: I have tried it out https://plnkr.co/edit/b46zOvlrWtEktwXzb717?p=preview Everything works fine except that the data in the dropdown gets appended to the previous records on each keyup event. Could you let me know if I've missed something. Thanks!

Comment: @San I guess you want to load all the options just once and them search with the keyup event in the options you just loaded if thats the case remove the ajax inside the keyup and add it inside the ready function to load it just once

Comment: In my actual code, I load the data from the database basing on the value that is sent as parameter to my url on every keyup. So in that case I don't want to load all the options at once. I would want to update the drop-down with new records fetched on each keyup event.

Comment: @San thats why I add this line in the answer  $('#mySelect option').each(function(){
        if (this.value == el.key) {
          exists = true;
        }
      }); to check if the record exists in the dropdown